# Effect on mass near a black hole

Tags: black-holes

When an object falls inside the event horizon with already huge terminal velocity directed towards the black hole, the gravity must accelerate to near light speeds which should  almost increase its relativistic mass to infinity, according to einsteins eqn
So does it mean that every object that falls into a black hole becomes a black hole itself?

Comment: Hi, I've linked a question that explains why fast moving masses don't turn into black holes. If you don't think this is a duplicate ping me and I'll withdraw my close vote.